# C# Entity Framework Update SaveChanges() is not updating DB entry

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Been working on this C# Entity Framework update problem for a bit now.  Maybe one of you can see what I'm missing.

The problem is within the `userEntry` portion of the code. I've traced through and made sure that `userEntry` is indeed populated with the information that I intend to update. When `entities.SaveChanges();` is invoked, the record is not updated in the database.

```
            int userId;
            using (Entities entities = new Entities())
            {
                MSIFeedStoreData feedStoreEntry = entities.MSIFeedStoreDatas
                    .FirstOrDefault((d) => d.Alias == user.Alias);

                if (Object.ReferenceEquals(feedStoreEntry, null))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("The user's alias could not be located in the feed store. The user cannot be added at this time.");
                }

                int feedStorePersonnelIdValue;
                if (Int32.TryParse(feedStoreEntry.PersonellID, out feedStorePersonnelIdValue))
                {
                    user.EmployeeId = feedStorePersonnelIdValue;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("DATABASE BUG CHECK: An entry was found in the feed store for this user but the personnel ID could not be parsed.");
                }

                MSIUser userEntry = entities.MSIUsers
                    .FirstOrDefault((u) => u.EmployeeID == feedStorePersonnelIdValue);

                if (Object.ReferenceEquals(userEntry, null))
                {
                    userEntry = Mapper.Map<MSIUser>(user);
                    userEntry = entities.MSIUsers.Add(userEntry);
                }
                else
                {
                    Mapper.DynamicMap<User, MSIUser>(user, userEntry);
                    entities.MSIUsers.Attach(userEntry);
                }

                userId = userEntry.MSIUser_ID;
                entities.SaveChanges();
            }

            return userId;
        }
```

Comment: You not changing anything. What are your expected results?

Comment: `Object.ReferenceEquals(feedStoreEntry, null)` is much easier to read as `feedStoreEntry == null` and does the same thing.

Comment: The change is in here:
else
                {
                    Mapper.DynamicMap<User, MSIUser>(user, userEntry);
                    entities.MSIUsers.Attach(userEntry);
                }

There is a user entry passed in through an ajax PUT call.  user is then Mapped to userEntry through Mapper.DynamicMap<User, MSIUser>(user, userEntry);   I have verified through debugging that this is infact happening.

Comment: Don't call Attach after that, its already attached to the context when you loaded it. Unless your DynamicMap method returns a new object, in which case you need to attach as modified, not just plain attach. `entities.Entry(userEntry).State = EntityState.Modified;` after the Attach command.

Comment: Removing the attach worked.  After the dozens of changes I made, the attach being one of which, the attach has been blocking whatever the original issue was.

Thank you Charlie.

Feel free to provide an answer and I will select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the call to `Attach`, its already attached to the context.

Comment: Edited to reflect comments

Comment: Remembered what the original issue was.

`MSIUser userEntry = entities.MSIUsers
.FirstOrDefault((u) => u.EmployeeID == feedStorePersonnelIdValue);`

was originally written as

`MSIUser userEntry = entities.MSIUsers
.AsNoTracking()
.FirstOrDefault((u) => u.EmployeeID == feedStorePersonnelIdValue);`

Comment: I made a similar mistake in confusing `Attach` with `AddObject` - no clue if that's relevant to this question because I didn't read the code but wanted to put this here anyway :-)